# loop through multiple selections and edit individually in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In sublime text I used to use a shortcut that allowed me to tab through my multi selection and edit each element individually.

for example I would cmd+d a word then the shortcut would allow me to tab through each selection and edit them individually.

I haven't used sublime text in a month since I switched and can't even remember the shortcut I used to find the name of that action. so I don't even know if it was a plugin or a built in short cut.

is there a similar shortcut in vscode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [multi-select](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor) in VSCode using `alt+click`

 (can be changed to `cmd+click` in "Selection -> Switch to Cmd+Click for Multi-Cursor").

To tab through your selections install the [tab-through-selections extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danseethaler.tab-through-selections) and then use `cmd+shift+u` to start iterating (alternativley `ctrl` in Windows), then:

- `tab` to go to the next selection
- `shift+tab` to go to the previous selection
- click anywhere to cancel iterating

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is it not possible without using plugins?