# Generate editable cursor positions on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

For example, if you create an HTML snippet with Emmet, I noticed that it generates some cursor positions where you can switch easily pressing `Tab`. e.g., if you type:

```
ul>li*4
```

It will generate four `li` items inside a `ul`, and a position cursor in the middle of each `<li>|</li>`, so when you finish editing one, you press `Tab` and jumps to the next cursor automatically.

[image]

Is it possible to create those manually? Like selecting multiple places of the code and edit one by one pressing `Tab` to switch forward?

Comment: See the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danseethaler.tab-through-selections

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! You can put it as an answer to mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen it before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209638/836330 and so you should upvote that answer.  And close this as a duplicate.